# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, artificial-intelligence, virtual

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PIno.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVeB.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0cAg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wpKr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTGh.jpg)
I'm creating an AI Virtual that talks to Twitch chat in real time, and when I hit chat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz2Fe.jpg)
This is how the error pops up
Help, friends, I can't figure this out.

I've re-downloaded vs code and tried all sorts of formulas, but it's not working. I think I'm missing something. I need help from the experts.